# Increase Wordpress Site Width CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width

Working on the following site: http://tinyurl.com/oqyltlw

The client wants me to make the site wider. Currently it is set to what looks to be 1000 pixels. Any way I can make it 1040px easily with CSS? The content boxes can remain the same width and in the same place, it's just the tan background size that needs to be increased. I went through a few style sheets, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `page` section which is holding all the elements inside your client's website. You can adjust its width by editing the `style.css` file of the theme. The current width is set to 1040px but you can increase it as per your needs.

```
#page {
    width: 1040px;
}
```